# Change size of mat-icon-button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

How can I change mat-icon-button size? My icon has 24px now and I would like to increase that value to 48px. I use mat-icon as a button content. I also noticed that mat-icon-button has just hardcoded 40px/40px size.

```
<button mat-icon-button color="primary">
    <mat-icon class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Answer (score 62):

### With Angular 8+

resizing worked for me with:

```css
.small-icon-button {
   width: 24px !important;
   height: 24px !important;
   line-height: 24px !important;

   .mat-icon {
      width: 16px !important;
      height: 16px !important;
      line-height: 16px !important;
   }
   .material-icons {
      font-size: 16px !important;
   }
}
```

No `::ng-deep` required.

### Angular 15+ Update:

For the new MDC components it is slightly different.
You can also check my **directive** for having different icon-button-sizes.
https://github.com/btxtiger/mat-icon-button-sizes

```scss
.small-icon-button {
   width: 24px !important;
   height: 24px !important;
   padding: 0px !important;
   display: inline-flex !important;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;

   & > *[role=img] {
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;

      svg {
         width: 16px;
         height: 16px;
      }
   }

   .mat-mdc-button-touch-target {
      width: 24px !important;
      height: 24px !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that really works without destroying the layout of the icon within the button.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. Add the `<button mat-mini-fab class="small-icon-button" ><mat-icon color="primary" >person</mat-icon></button>`

Comment: I found that the touch-target area didn't actually get adjusted with the above code. I had to wrap the `.mat-mdc-button-touch-target` selector within an `::ng-deep` for it to take effect:  ```::ng-deep { .mat-mdc-button-touch-target {...}}```

Answer (score 31):

Mat-icons are font images. To change their size you should override the font size of mat-icon.
For Angular Material 8+, add the following in the components stylesheet:

```
.mat-icon{
    font-size:48px !important; //make it bigger, the default being 24px. 
    width:48px;                //Do not forget to adjust the 
    height:48px;               //height and/or the width, as in the demo

}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdhzmv-pfyr9c?file=app/button-overview-example.html)

or directely in the HTML:

```
<mat-icon style="font-size:48px">mail</mat-icon>
```

---

For previous versions, you still can use ::ng-deep to reach that class deep in the host. The width and the height should be also set to adjust the backdrop size proportionally.

**HTML:**

```
<button mat-button>    
  <mat-icon class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</mat-icon>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
::ng-deep .mat-icon{
    height:48px !important;
    width:48px !important;
    font-size:48px !important;
}
```

Check out the [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdhzmv)

---

Or, if you avoid `::ng-deep`, use `ViewEncapsulation.None` (but use sparingly):

**Class:**

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Then you can style directly from the component stylesheet.

**CSS:**

```
.mat-icon{
    height:48px !important;
    width:48px !important;
    font-size:48px !important;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdhzmv-a4awvv)

---

Or style it from the main stylesheet, styles.css:

**styles.css**

```
.mat-icon{
    height:48px !important;
    width:48px !important;
    font-size:48px !important;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdhzmv-xgrzj2)

---

And last, but not the least solution, styling can be done inline:

**HTML:**

```
<button mat-button>    
  <mat-icon style="
    height:48px !important;
    width:48px !important;
    font-size:48px !important;" class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</mat-icon>
</button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdhzmv-5hqzq9)

Comment: This demo does not work. Just click on the button in your demo and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: `::ng-deep .mat-icon` rule worked for me, but I also had to add `line-height: 48px !important;` to fix vertical align

Comment: This stinks if I have multiple buttons in my component.  Would be nice to have an example overriding dimensions on specific button.

Comment: @Iostranslation, The last example is for a specific button. For the other versions, I guess you can add a class or an id on the specific button and add that reference in the css as well. Would that help?

Comment: There is also the way of using ::nth-of-type() with the number of the button. Works well. I could update the answer if it could help

Comment: This answers how to resize a `mat-icon` while OP specifically asked for mat-icon-button. Using the latest answer about Angular 8 only resizes the icon, while the underlying button remains as it was. The is not ideal as the ripple and the touch are aren't the same as the icon's

Comment: @Odys, it was working at the time I posted. You can try to add 'mat fab' directive  to the button and setting the style for .mat-fab

Answer (score 16):

In your component scss file (assuming sass):

```
.mat-icon-button.large {

    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;

    .mat-icon {
      font-size: 48px;
      width: 48px;
      height: 48px;
      line-height: 48px;
    }
  }
```

You can change to whatever sizes you want for both the button and the icon. If they are both set to 48 that will not have any spacing around the icon. You may want to increase the button size to something like 64.

In your html:

```
<button mat-icon-button class="large"><mat-icon>chat</mat-icon></button>
```

Comment: This answer works but doesn't scale up well, not for 64. By default there is padding between the icon and the button, using this answer for 64 there is no padding.

Answer (score 9):

Many answers unnecessarily complicated... Here is what worked for me using **Angular 9**:

Assuming you want your icon to be 40x40:

**HTML**:

```
<button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon id="add">add</mat-icon>
</button>
```

**CSS**:

```
.mat-icon {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 40px; // DO NOT FORGET IT !
}
```

No need `ng-deep` or `!important`.

Comment: This happens to work with 40, but doesn't work with more. It is not ideal.

Comment: This well reduces the size of the icon, but not of the surrounding button, meaning there is no gain is space.

Comment: @yglodt Applying the same styling to `.mat-icon-button` works for the button. In my case I also had to wrap the `<mat-icon>` in a `<label>` for the icon to correctly vertically align.

Comment: This is cleanest.. you may need to play also with   margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -8px; to center your icon with button area etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using scss defined in the styles.scss to get round any encapsulation issues (defining it in a custom theme will also do the same). There is an added level of specificity to avoid using **!important**.

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icon-button-sizing?embed=1&file=src/styles.scss) for it.

**html**

```
<h3>Normal button</h3>
<button mat-icon-button color="warn" aria-label="normal button">
    <mat-icon>cloud_upload</mat-icon>
  </button>

<h3>Large Button</h3>
<button mat-icon-button color="warn" class="icon-button-large" aria-label="small button">
    <mat-icon>cloud_upload</mat-icon>
  </button>

<h3>small button</h3>
<button mat-icon-button color="warn" class="icon-button-small" aria-label="large icon">
    <mat-icon>cloud_upload</mat-icon>
</button>
```

**style.scss**

```
button[mat-icon-button]{
$large-size-button: 80px;
$large-size-icon: 48px;

    &.icon-button-large {
      width: $large-size-button;
      height: $large-size-button;
      line-height: $large-size-button;
    .mat-icon {
      font-size: $large-size-icon;
      width: $large-size-icon;
      height: $large-size-icon;
      line-height: $large-size-icon;
    }
    .mat-button-ripple {
      font-size: inherit;
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
    }
  }

  $small-size-button: 24px;
  $small-size-icon: 18px;

    &.icon-button-small {
      width: $small-size-button;
      height: $small-size-button;
      line-height: $small-size-button;
    .mat-icon {
      font-size: $small-size-icon;
      width: $small-size-icon;
      height: $small-size-icon;
      line-height: $small-size-icon;
    }
    .mat-button-ripple {
      font-size: inherit;
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Best answer. Handles icons, padding, button, ripple. Doesnt require `::ng-deep`. Cudos

Answer (score 4):

I know this question was posted a while back, but I like using the `zoom` CSS property, because it is a very simple and elegant solution and avoids several caveats.

Make sure the specificity of the selector is enough to override Angular Material's styles.  This helps to avoid using the `!important` override, which is generally frowned upon.

```css
button[mat-icon-button].mat-icon-button.large-icon-button {
  zoom: 1.5;  // NOTE: You may need to adjust this value to achieve exactly 48px.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using this scss styles in angular 12:

```
$sizes: [17, 20, 25, 35, 40];
@each $size in $sizes {
  button.mat-icon-button {
    &[size="#{$size}"] {
      line-height: initial;
      min-width: auto;
      height: #{$size}px;
      width: #{$size}px;
      .mat-button-wrapper {
        line-height: initial;
        mat-icon {
          height: auto;
          width: auto;
          line-height: initial;
          font-size: #{$size * .7}px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't work with sizes less than 17, but I don't think you would need this.
Hope it'll help you out :)

Answer (score 2):

Addition to this great answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57759753/2376477

In order to reduce code boilerplate for different sizes I applied scss mixin

```scss
@mixin mat-icon-size($button-size, $icon-size) {

  width: $button-size !important;
  height: $button-size !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  display: inline-flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  & > *[role=img] {
    width: $icon-size;
    height: $icon-size;
    font-size: $icon-size;

    svg {
      width: $icon-size;
      height: $icon-size;
    }
  }

  .mat-mdc-button-touch-target {
    width: $button-size !important;
    height: $button-size !important;
  }
}

$mat-icon-sizes: (
  '24': (24px, 16px),
  '36': (36px, 24px),
  '72': (72px, 48px),
);

@each $name, $sizes in $mat-icon-sizes {
  .mat-icon-size-#{$name} {
    @include mat-icon-size(nth($sizes, 1), nth($sizes, 2));
  }
}
```

And use it like this

```html
<button mat-icon-button class="mat-icon-size-72"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>
```

I prefer specific numbers but of course you can name it `sm`, `md`, `lg`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For the new MDC components the right way to do it is using the css variables that are already provided:

```
button {
      --mdc-icon-button-state-layer-size: 24px;
      --mdc-icon-button-icon-size: 20px;
      padding: 0;
}
```

No need ng-deep or !important.

Comment: This partially works. I shaved a few more pixels off. Not sure why it is so difficult to change the height of Angular Material components. I have spent an hour on this.

Answer (score 1):

Working perfectly in Angular 9:

```
<button mat-mini-fab>
  <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
</button>
```

docs: https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples

Answer (score 1):

Setting `[inline]="true"` as stated in the [Angular Material Icon Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api#MatIcon) can be used for mat-icon and works inside a button of type `mat-icon-button`:

> ...automatically sizing the icon to match the font size of the element the icon is contained in.

HTML:

```html
<button mat-icon-button class="material-icons" color="primary">
    <mat-icon [inline]="true">play_circle_filled</mat-icon>
</button>
```

CSS:

```css
.material-icons {
  font-size: 2em
}
```

The `inline` Input Property sets currently the following css for you, which is similar as other answers already suggested:

```css
.mat-icon.mat-icon-inline {
    font-size: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```

For something as simple as the mat-icon component this looks like more overhead than using css in the first place.

Comment: I tried this solution, but the mat-icon does not stay centered in the mat-icon-button when it is resized.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <button md-mini-fab (click)="add()" 
    style="cursor: pointer;textdecoration:none;height:30px;width:30px">                                               
    <md-icon style="margin:-4px 1px;color:white;font-size: 16px;">add</md-icon>
    </button>
```

above code working perfectly in angular2

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers managed to change the size of the "touch target" for me, and so does no one else (see GitHub issue).

So building on [Bop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76330092/11763719), here's what worked for me (using SASS variable to only have to change size value in one place):

```
button {
  $icon-size: 20px; // SASS variable

  --mdc-icon-button-icon-size: #{$icon-size};
  --mdc-icon-button-state-layer-size: #{$icon-size + 8};
  padding: 0;

  .mat-icon {
    height: $icon-size;
    width: $icon-size;
    font-size: $icon-size;
  }

  // https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27118
  ::ng-deep span.mat-mdc-button-touch-target {
    height: #{$icon-size + 8};
    width: #{$icon-size + 8};
  }
}
```